# Strange swirls on the latest image from SOHO

Tags: the-sun, image-processing, soho

Earlier today, I was looking at the [latest image from SOHO](https://soho.nascom.nasa.gov/data/realtime/hmi_igr/512/) and noticed some odd swirly lines at the bottom left of the image. They no longer appear on the site, but I saved the image before they were removed.
[image]
What are these lines? Do they mean anything, or is it just some artifact of the image generation process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the astronomical considerations, but compare this to the same part of a newer image:

[image: Fraction of image from question]

[image: Fraction of SOHO image October 18 2023]

This is almost certainly just **text rendering gone wrong.** Notice in particular that the rightmost part is four circular shapes, which would be zeroes; the tall "("-like shapes are where "2"s should be, and other such similarities in the sequence of glyphs.

Somehow the software used to put the text on the image misread the font data, and produced incorrect shapes.

I'd say it's using an old-school vector font (as might be have been originally designed for CRT vector displays, CNC engravers, or any display device that only makes lines): it is always a line of exactly 1 pixel thickness. Something caused the software to misinterpret the intended length or angle of each segment, but they were still being taken as a single polyline, so you get a vaguely coherent curve but not legible text.

Comment: It's an old-school vector font from [IDL](https://www.nv5geospatialsoftware.com/Products/IDL), a very common environment for remote sensing and older astronomy projects.

Comment: There is also  a  /  and -  in about the right place.